# Node error stack trace is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stack-overflow

I have some long-running node code that will print a `[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]` error after a while and continue to do so indefinitely.

To track down what recursive call is causing this (I couldn't find anywhere recursive that I wasn't using either a `setTimeout` or `process.nextTick` on), I did this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(error.stack);
});
```

This caught the error, but the `stack` property is `undefined`! I tried throwing my own error and the `stack` property shows the expected stack. Is node not supposed to have a `stack` in a stack overflow error? How can I pinpoint which calls are causing this?

Comment: Does `console.trace` produce something that is more meaningful?

Comment: try `console.log(error.stack || error`... this will print the stack if the `error` argument is of type `Error`... If it is of type `String`, it will plainly print the message...

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to throw an `Error` object in JavaScript. This can even be a string. So you cannot rely on the `stack` attribute to be defined when your app crashes.

From what you are describing you have a memory leak in your app which you should try to find. There are many tutorials online. There is also a module that can find a leak called `memwatch` on https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch.

Comment: Stackoverflow exceptions are certainly `Error` instances in any case.

Comment: But does the `uncaughtException` event not catch any unhandled exception? Apart from that you probably should not use it at all?